# Which SQL queries must be written as dynamic and cannot use static sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Which SQL queries must be written as dynamic SQL and cannot use static SQL? Can you give me an example and say why? I had this question in one test, but I couldn't find any example. I think all queries can be written as static SQL.

Comment: Any query that has an unknown number of columns is an example that cannot be written using "static" SQL

Comment: An example of Dynamic SQL would be what PHPMyAdmin uses . Where the user can generate their own query `SELECT`-ing nth columns

Comment: As a matter of terminology, virtually _all_ modern use of SQL is dynamic SQL. That is, sending an SQL query to the RDBMS server as a string to be parsed at runtime. That's dynamic SQL. What is not dynamic SQL? SQL that is parsed at compile-time. Hardly anyone does this anymore, but it was common in the 1980's and 90's. Also stored procedures that do not use PREPARE and EXECUTE are also not dynamic SQL. Queries in a stored proc are parsed when you create the proc.

Comment: @Bill Karwin -- When you log into MySQLServer using command line and create, delete, drop, truncate etc etc --  and even use plain queries -- is that all not static?  I would venture to say "Hardly anyone does this anymore" is a stretch?

Comment: In the role of DBA, designer, performance analyser/tuning,maintenance etc , I use *static* SQL probably the vast majority of the time. As a developer I would use dynamic SQL occaisionally - usually more for maintenance; as a developer using a client-side library eg an ORM I would be technically using dynamic SQL all the time since the ORM will be building the required SQL based on the language construct/mappings, but we don't tend to think of this; it's always been my uderstanding that *dynamic SQL* was any SQL statement built by a static query and subsequently executed.

Comment: @Zak, In that example, is the SQL parsed at compile time? No -- you aren't recompiling the mysql CLI tool every time you execute an SQL statement. You are sending strings to the server and they are parsed there. That's what dynamic SQL is.

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous use-cases where Dynamic SQL is beneficial or necessary, and vary depending on specific database platforms.

Generally andything involving *data Definition Language (DDL)* can only use literals and cannot be parameterised, so this requires Dynamic SQL. For example, a procedure that takes the name of a table and a column as paramters must use Dynamic SQL in order to construct a query that can select the specified column from the specified table.

Another use-case would be for pivoting rows into columns, where the number/name of the columns can vary but must be "baked" into the query prior to compilation, the columns that need to be referenced by the query are read from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and used to build the necessary syntax.

Yet another might be for generating a new table on the fly based off of an existing table speficied by a variable, where the `create table` syntax requires specific column names - these are retrieved from the system catalog `information schema` views to construct the desired `create table` statement.

There are too many more cases to mention but you get the idea!

Answer (score 0):

If an application allows the user to use their own selection or filtering criteria, and that selection or filtering criteria must/should be done by the SQL server and not in the application space, it must be done using a dynamically built query.

Answer (score 0):

If the query has variable columns/inputs, it must be generated via dynamic SQL.  One example could be a stored procedure that allows a user to search for changes on a set of columns in a specified table.  In order for this to properly function dynamically, you couldn't write this without generating the statements.